# WinForms WebView2 not showing pdf draw tools

Tags: winforms, controls, draw, pdf-viewer, webview2

I have a WinForms application and a form with WebView2 control.  I set Source property of the Webview2 control to a local pdf file.  When I run the program, the pdfviewer is showing the pdf document, but the draw and highlight controls are not showing.

When I open the pdf in edge browser, the controls are showing.  Where am I doing the mistake.

Comment: Have you updated your run-time / Canary? Did you update the Control via NuGet? -- The standard behavior, when the PDF file is passed to the `Source` property, is to show the PDF toolbar. Do you see it? -- It doesn't mean that all options are available: the WebView2 Control is not Edge.

Comment: Yes, I have latest runtime as well as canary installed on my system.  Even the application worked as expected (i.e. with draw and highlight controls visible).  However, of late the controls are not showing up.

Comment: Can you clarify whether you see the PDF Toolbar but no editing tools are present, or you don't see the Toolbar at all.

Comment: I am seeing the pdf toolbar.  But the controls namely  read aloud, draw, highlight and erase are not showing.

Comment: Those parts of PDF in WebView2 are disabled. You can open a feature request on https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Feedback

Comment: I didn't notice your comment. -- WebView2 is a work in progress, you may see features that come and go. The next release will add the option to disable some of the Toolbar Buttons. Other features may be enabled in the future. For now, the Toolbar you see is what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The feature to annotate PDFs is disabled in WebView2. You can read more about this on [Disabling Feature: PDF Annotations Support](https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Announcements/issues/21).

Additionally, you can open a feature request to enable this feature on the [WebView2 Feedback repo](https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Feedback/issues).

Comment: [Tracking in #38](https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Feedback/issues/38)

Comment: The annotations feature was disabled separately from the feature to control which icons show up in the PDF toolbar. If you're interested in the PDF annotations feature in WebView2 you should consider making a new feature request.

Comment: The feature was very useful. It made my life easy in many of my projects.  As suggested by @DavidRisney I already made a feature request. 

Any of you, please suggest me libraries or tools to annotate pdf.